# Which implementations of IHttpActionResult exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have identified these pre-defined responses:

```
Ok - 200
NotFound - 404
Exception - 500
Unauthorized - 401
BadRequest - 400
Conflict
Redirect
InvalidModelState
```

But I can't find any docs about the total range of helper methods that exist..Are there any more? 
I've tried Microsoft site and only found [these](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) docs but they don't list them at all..

Help appreciated

Comment: Do you need a list of the possible HTTP-return-values? There are many many more than those 5. Anyway such questions are off-topic here on SO.

Comment: There is also `ResponseMessageResult` which is a really handy one as it allows you to return an arbitrary `HttpResponseMessage`. There are a number of others defined in [System.Web.Http.Results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results(v=vs.118).aspx). Note that what you have actually listed in your question are methods on the [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx) class that happen to return `IHttpActionResult` implementations.

Comment: I think Marcus means that he is looking for pre-defined responses. I think these are all that comes out-of-the-box. If you want more you can always inherit from the IHttpActionResult. I did this for Forbidden response

Comment: What about my favourite: `418 - I´m a teapot`?

Comment: @VasilIndzhev You are correct. Updated my question

Comment: @HimBromBeere I was looking for the predefined versions of IHttpActionResult. Not the total. Sorry for not clearing that out in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you select ApiController and press F12 you will see the definition of it. There are listed all the helpers.

[image]

If you want to create a custom one here is an example:

```
public class ForbiddenResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly HttpRequestMessage _request;
    private readonly string _reason;

    public ForbiddenResult(HttpRequestMessage request,string reason)
    {
        _request = request;
        _reason = reason;
    }

    public ForbiddenResult(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _request = request;
        _reason = "Forbidden";
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,_reason);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vasil. Of course they are under ApiController class..Also nice implementation example of the interface

Comment: @MarcusH You can not find any documentation in WebApi implementation, because it's `HttpStatusCode`, that you can found at [MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)